# How to: JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization

i have been trying to find a way to deserialize this in C# but unfortunately without luck,,

i would really appreciate it if someone can help, here is the json data:

```
{
"138c399": [
    "A1E67B",
    39.826,
    -76.9241,
    238,
    15400,
    402,
    "2573",
    "T-KDCA1",
    "B772",
    "N221UA",
    1367747636,
    "KWI",
    "IAD",
    "UA981",
    0,
    -1280,
    "UAL981",
    1367748699
],
"138c3c8": [
    "89911F",
    45.3878,
    25.8222,
    290,
    35975,
    460,
    "2362",
    "T-LROP1",
    "B744",
    "B-18711",
    1367747646,
    "TPE",
    "FRA",
    "CI5621",
    0,
    0,
    "CAL5621",
    1367754205
],
"full_count": 3796,
"version": 4
```

}

EDIT: I changed the json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this :) (Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/))

```
var flights = JObject.Parse(json)
                .Children().Cast<JProperty>()
                .Select(p => new { Key = p.Name, Values = p.Value.ToArray() })
                .Select(j => new 
                {
                    id = j.Key,
                    hex = (string)j.Values[0],
                    lat = double.Parse(j.Values[1].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    lon = double.Parse(j.Values[2].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    dir = (int)j.Values[3],
                    alt = (int)j.Values[4],
                    speed = (int)j.Values[5],
                    radar = (string)j.Values[7],
                    plane = (string)j.Values[8],
                    reg = (string)j.Values[9],
                    time = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)j.Values[10])),
                    from = (string)j.Values[11],
                    to = (string)j.Values[12],
                    callsign = (string)j.Values[13],
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: ur awesome, i didnt know that such library exists, but can help help parsing the new json data structure,,

Answer (score 1):

Try [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class

```
var _object = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(yourJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx, awesome class for all stuff regarding seralize and deserialize json, xml into objects and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Json.NET as YvesR suggested, it is in fact used by Microsoft as well these days (in ASP.NET MVC Web API) - they essentially tossed the support for their internal JSON serialization technology (i.e. JavaScriptSerializer).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) is the worth reading article on JSON Serialization and Deserialization. Hope this will help you.